# 404 index() function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

Well, when I try to access to:

```
http://example.com/index.php/pages/index
```

I have no problem, but when I try with:

```
http://example.com/index.php/pages
```

I have an 404 error.

My controller's code:

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        echo "index page";
    }

    public function view($page = 'home'){
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

My routes config:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Comment: Is your controller inside a subfolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.php`, add the following line of code above the line: `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';`

`$route['pages'] = 'pages';`

If that doesn't work try commenting the line `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` and check the url: `http://example.com/index.php/pages`